# Meaning of "gambled" in "whose wasted right hand gambled against his left" (Aurora Leigh)

Tags: meaning, elizabeth-barrett-browning, aurora-leigh

From [Aurora Leigh](http://digital.library.upenn.edu/women/barrett/aurora/aurora.html#1) - what is the meaning of **gambled** here? It's hard to understand. I first thought his wasted right hand was somehow pinned to his left one using the brass button, but the dictionaries have only the "game-of-chance" meaning for the word **gamble**.

> Two hours afterward,
>   Within St. Margaret’s Court I stood alone,
>   Close-veiled. A sick child, from an ague-fit,
>   Whose wasted right hand **gambled** ’gainst his left
>   With an old brass button; in a blot of sun,
>   Jeered weakly at me as I passed across
>   The uneven pavement; while a woman, rouged
>   Upon the angular cheek-bones, kerchief torn,
>   Thin dangling locks, and flat lascivious mouth,
>   Cursed at a window, both ways, in and out,
>   By turns some bed-rid creature and myself,—
>   ‘Lie still there, mother! liker the dead dog
>   You’ll be to-morrow. What, we pick our way,

Comment: It might be a poetic spelling of *gamboled* (from *gambol*: run or jump about playfully), or a play on words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child is playing a game of chance, with one hand competing against the other, for want of a companion to play against.

Here are a couple of examples from other works, to show how the phrase is used:

> One summer afternoon at Capua I was sitting on a stone bench behind the stables of my villa, thinking out some problem of Etruscan history and idly shooting dice, **left hand against right**, on the rough plank table in front of me.
>
> <sub>Robert Graves (1934). [*I, Claudius*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.226782/page/n221).</sub>

> I sat near her on the floor, playing knucklebones, **right hand against left**.
>
> <sub>Mary Stewart (1970). [*The Crystal Cave*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LvaqcjjVp2YC&pg=PT16).</sub>

What kind of game of chance might be played with a brass button? Perhaps the button is spun to see how it lands; or perhaps the game is played with some other equipment (for example, [knucklebones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knucklebones) can be played with small bones or pebbles) and the brass button is the stake or prize.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the word gamble is a bit incomplete. While the most common usage is with games on chance (i.e. betting money), broader sense is an risk:

> [Gamble](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gamble)
>
> [as a verb]  Take risky action in the hope of a desired result.
>
> [as a noun] A risky action undertaken with the hope of success.

So how I would interpret the line is that since the child's right hand is wasted, that is a "risk" to try to get the button away from his left. The child is playing a game with themselves the "desired result" being the right hand winning the button from the left.